# how to update the instance's Capacity Reservation settings during EC2 instance startup?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

How to update the instance’s capacity reservation settings during EC2 instance startup?

Below is the aws-cli used to update by stopping an instance, but I m looking for a parameter to update while EC2 instance is created, so I don’t want to just stop the instance to update this setting.

```sh
aws ec2 modify-instance-capacity-reservation-attributes \
    --instance-id i-example \
    --capacity-reservation-specification 'CapacityReservationTarget={CapacityReservationId= cr-example} --region us-east-1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify Instance Capacity Reservation is used to modify the Capacity Reservation setting associated for an instance. If you are launching an instance and want to target a specific Capacity Reservation with that instance, while launching an EC2 instance, using run-instances API you can specify the capacity-reservation-specification:

```
> aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-abc12345 --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --key-name MyKeyPair --subnet-id subnet-1234567890abcdef1 --capacity-reservation-specification CapacityReservationTarget={CapacityReservationId=cr-a1234567}
```

For additional info, you can refer to: [Launching instances into an existing Capacity Reservation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/capacity-reservations-using.html#capacity-reservations-launch)